# mapping tab key in vim

Tags: c++, vim, tabs, keymapping

I'm using Vim 7.4. I have mapped "Tab" key in normal mode to switch to insert mode.

```
nnoremap <tab> a
```

This works fine in .txt file but not in .cpp files. Why is that?

Besides mapping, I also have clang_complete settings in my .vimrc file.

Comment: Do you put your map setting in .vimrc or do you invoke it from command line?

Comment: Just a bit of (I suppose, unasked for, but hopefully helpful) advice -- there are a bunch of different ways (`a`, `A`, `i`, `I`, `o`, `O`, and probably some more obscure ones) to enter insert mode, and they have different purposes. Knowing how to use them all, not just `a`, will probably serve you well.

Answer (score 2):

```
:verbose nmap <Tab>
```

will show you the current mapping(s). If two are listed, the one with an `@` prefix before the right-hand side is a *buffer-local* mapping that overrides your global one. You then need to find its definition (somewhere in `ftplugin/cpp*.vim`, or via an `:autocmd FileType cpp`) and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I put it using:

```
map <Tab> to
```

and it worked